# Read the sum value from the column footer in UI - Grid?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm currently trying to read my column footer to make sure that the total sum from the aggregate is exactly 100. However I can not find a way to get that value from the grid functions. Maybe I missed a function in the docs. Is there a way to accomplish this or will I have to manually loop through my grid and sum the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregates on the column footer to automatically show the sum of all the values in the column.

you can have your grid config like below

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    showGridFooter: true,
    showColumnFooter: true,
    enableFiltering: true,
    columnDefs: [
        { field: 'name', width: '13%' },
        { field: 'address.street',aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.sum, width: '13%' },
        { field: 'age', aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.avg, aggregationHideLabel: true, width: '13%' },
        { name: 'ageMin', field: 'age', aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.min, width: '13%', displayName: 'Age for min' },
        { name: 'ageMax', field: 'age', aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.max, width: '13%', displayName: 'Age for max' },
        { name: 'customCellTemplate', field: 'age', width: '14%', footerCellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" style="background-color: Red;color: White">custom template</div>' },
        { name: 'registered', field: 'registered', width: '20%', cellFilter: 'date', footerCellFilter: 'date', aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.max }
    ],
    data: data,
    onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
            $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    }
};
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/nv1eJAIyD5xNDn8XI6L9?p=preview

To get the value from the footer, provided you know the column index and have a reference to the gridApi.

```
$scope.getFooterValue = function()
{
  console.log($scope.gridApi);
  alert($scope.gridApi.grid.columns[2].getAggregationValue());
}
```

Comment: I already am doing this. What I would like to do is then take the value of that aggregate and use it elsewhere in my javascript.

Comment: updated the plnkr. You need to use the ref to the gridApi.